# Anychart DATETIME axis with just TIME 00:00 to 23:59:59

Tags: anychart

I am using Anychart Version =  8.1.0.1792.

I want to display several series of temperature values on same line chart (each series has data for a 24-hour period), each series has a different date.  I would like to have x-axis as fixed time ticks from 00:00 to 23:59:59 and plot the data irrespective of the DATE, just use the TIME values in the dataset.

Currently, anychart creates the datetime x-axis values based upon the data... which includes the DATE as well as the TIME.  How can I create my x-axis to be fixed and then use line chart to only look at the TIME values (ignore the DATE) in my different datasets of temp data?

Thanks for any help!
Dave

Comment: Implementation of this feature may depend on the chart type you use. Do you use stock line chart, scatter or ordinal line chart? Knowing this will help me prepare a proper example for you, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var chart = anychart.line([[Date.UTC(2014, 9, 8, 13, 5, 0), 511.53, 500.98,680.79, 656.40],
[Date.UTC(2014, 9, 8, 13, 28, 9), 900, 850, 1100, 1050]]);

var axis = chart.xAxis();
var formatLabels = axis.labels();
formatLabels.textFormatter(function () {
    // Sets format for datetime.
    return anychart.format.dateTime(this.value, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 300);
});
```